# Perl sort hash and overwrites/add to new variable

Tags: perl, hash

I'm quite new to perl and I need to find a way to sort hash. Many examples will run the sort then will just print to console. I need the new hash variable contain the key by sorted.

For example:

```
my %planets = (
  Mercury => 0.4,
  Venus   => 0.7,
  Earth   => 1,
);
 
foreach my $name (sort keys %planets) {
    printf "this $name \n";
}
```

I mean instead of printing I need to reference it back to another variable or even the `%planets` itself.

So my expected final hash will be

```
%new_hash = (
    Earth => 1,
    Mercury => 0.4,
    Venus => 0.7
);
```

Comment: _I need the new hash variable contain the key by sorted_. Isn't it sorted with `values`?

Comment: https://www.perl.com/article/27/2013/6/16/Perl-hash-basics-create-update-loop-delete-and-sort/ according to this "Sort by alphabetical" shows that we can sort by keys. I need to know how to reference it or put it under a new hash.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There's no such thing as a sorted hash.

---

Nothing says you have to iterate over the result of `sort`. You can store it in an array for later use.

```perl
my @sorted_keys = sort keys(%planets);
```

---

Another possibility is to convert the data structure you are using as you sort.

```perl
my @sorted_planets =
   map { [ $_, $planets{$_} ] }
      sort keys(%planets);
```

This produces:

```perl
my @sorted_planets = (
   [ Earth   => 1   ],
   [ Mercury => 0.4 ],
   [ Venus   => 0.7 ],
);
```